# Are there any projects in ASP.NET MVC4 similar to ActiveAdmin in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In Rails there is a gem called [ActiveAdmin](http://www.activeadmin.info/), which is a robust administration tool for a website.  Are there any similar plugins/projects for ASP.NET MVC4 availale through NuGet, CodePlex, or GitHub?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  I can't find anything and would like to know if a project has been started since .NET now has dynamic lanuage support.  Should this have been asked somewhere else?

Comment: I would also like to know... The question wasn't asking for any recommendation, it was "Does something like this exist?"